# angular forms with multiple sync validators are valid despite it should be invalid

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I have 2 FormControls.

When one of the controls value is greater/small than the value of the other control I get correct error validations written in my html and the form.valid is TRUE.

```
this.bestGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators(bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator(this.worstGradeScoresFormControl), 
Validators.max(100)]);
this.worstGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators(worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator(this.bestGradeScoresFormControl));
```

Then I added the Validators.max(100) to the bestScores control using the Compose function:

```
this.bestGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators(Validators.compose(
[bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator(this.worstGradeScoresFormControl), Validators.max(100)]));
this.worstGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators(worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator(this.bestGradeScoresFormControl));
```

When I set 101 scores for the best score control I get: 'More than 100 scores are not allowed' and the form.valid is FALSE, that is CORRECT!

but...

when I change now the worst scores control value to a valid one then the previous 'max error' suddenly disappers and the form.valid is TRUE, that is NOT CORRECT!

Instead of using the Compose method I also tried using an array of validators like:

```
this.bestGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators([bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator(this.worstGradeScoresFormControl), Validators.max(100)]);
  this.worstGradeScoresFormControl.setValidators(worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator(this.bestGradeScoresFormControl));
```

The behavior is the same ???

What is wrong here? Why does changing the worstScore control value the form.valid value from FALSE to TRUE ?

```
export const bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator = (worstScoreControl: FormControl): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    if (control.value > worstScoreControl.value) {
      worstScoreControl.setErrors(null);
      control.setErrors(null);
    }
    else {
      worstScoreControl.setErrors({ "bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScores": true });
      return { 'bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScores': true };
    }
  };
}

export const worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator = (bestScoreControl: FormControl): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    if (control.value < bestScoreControl.value) {
      bestScoreControl.setErrors(null);
      control.setErrors(null);
    }
    else {
      bestScoreControl.setErrors({ "worstScoresSmallerThanBestScores": true });
      return { 'worstScoresSmallerThanBestScores': true };
    }
  };
}
```

UPDATE

I have put a plunkr here to show the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ygiVNtPImkMveLGogTk2?p=preview

In my opinion the solution can NOT be that I create a unique custom validator on the whole Form because I want all the custom validations have in its own validator class/function.

If you make the solution basing on my plunkr code work, then the bounty is yours :-)

Comment: Check your code `bestScoreControl.setErrors(null);`. You're resetting errors for opposite control

Comment: I investigated why I have done this once and come to this conclusion: When worst score has 20 and best score 19 both are displaying a red error message. When I lower the worst score to 18 the error message for worst score disappears, but the error message for the best scores remains. That means when I leave... the invalid form state by going to 18 with worst score nothing triggers/updates the validity of the best score control. Therefore I did what you have found out. That worked nice so far until I was trying multiple validators...

Comment: It seems I have to introduce again  the updateValueAndValidity() on each value change of the opposite control.

Comment: Finally I think I need a way to clear/remove a certain error from a control. I want to remove that the worst score is OK too when the best score has a higher score and the same time I do not want to remove the error that best scores has a max of 100.  But that feature/function does not exist :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that there is no such feature like add/remove specific error for angular form control errors you can implement it yourself.

```typescript
function addError(control: AbstractControl, errorKey: string) {
  const errors = control.errors || {};
  errors[errorKey] = true;

  control.setErrors(errors);
}

function removeError(control: AbstractControl, errorKey: string) {
  const errors = control.errors || {};
  delete errors[errorKey];

  control.setErrors(Object.keys(errors).length ? errors : null)
}
```

Now just add or remove error whenever you need it in your custom validators:

**bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator**

```typescript
export const bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScoresValidator = 
                              (worstScoreControl: FormControl): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {

    if (control.value > worstScoreControl.value) {
      removeError(worstScoreControl, 'worstScoresSmallerThanBestScores')
      return null;
    }
    else {
      addError(worstScoreControl, 'worstScoresSmallerThanBestScores');
      return { 'bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScores': true };
    }

  };
}
```

**worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator**

```typescript
export const worstScoresSmallerThanBestScoresValidator = 
                               (bestScoreControl: FormControl): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {

    if (control.value < bestScoreControl.value) {
      removeError(bestScoreControl, 'bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScores')
      return null;
    }
    else {
      addError(bestScoreControl, 'bestScoresGreaterThanWorstScores');
      return { 'worstScoresSmallerThanBestScores': true };
    }
  };
}
```

**[ng-run example](https://ng-run.com/edit/J1GG7GN9dFh6lQi0tElb?open=app%2Fvalidators.ts)**

Comment: The coolest thing about your code is the delete operator ;-) did not know that exist!